# Every Brahmin does aachman (purification) in the name of Vishnu. Then on whose name shukracharya will do so (aachman)?

Tags: rituals, vedic-rituals, shukracharya

Is shukracharya does aachman in the name of Vishnu or any other way? Because every Brahmin does aachman in the name of Vishnu. So what about shukracharya who hates Vishnu.

Comment: Who said shukracharya hates vishnu ? Even so, even when asuras do tapasya they have to follow rules of shastra, otherwise they won't get power.

Comment: The prescribed Achamana mantras in Atharva Veda Sandhya Vandana are four mantras starting with "Jeevastha jeevyasam....." from the Veda itself.

Answer (score 8):

> Because every Brahmin does aachman in the name of Vishnu

That is obviously not true.

First of all, the Smarta achamana, which is prescribed in Manu Smriti and several other Smritis, **does not require any mantras to be chanted. Simply sipping the water is sufficient.**

And, since Smritis talk only about Vedic rituals, so we can conclude in Vedic rituals this achamana is to be done. Chanting mantras are not required.

Description of achamana from Manu Smriti is as follows:

> 2.58. Let a Brahmana always sip water out of the part of the hand (tirtha) sacred to Brahman, or out of that sacred to Ka (Pragapati),
>   or out of (that) sacred to the gods, never out of that sacred to the
>   manes.
>
> 2.59. They call (the part) at the root of the thumb the tirtha sacred to Brahman, that at the root of the (little) finger (the tirtha)
>   sacred to Ka (Pragapati), (that) at the tips (of the fingers, the
>   tirtha) sacred to the gods, and that below (between the index and the
>   thumb, the tirtha) sacred to the manes
>
> 2.60. Let him first sip water thrice; next twice wipe his mouth; and, lastly, touch with water the cavities (of the head), (the seat of) the
>   soul and the head.

So, no use of any mantras at all.

Similarly, Apasthmbha describes the process as follows:

> He should not sip water standing or stooping.  Let him sufficient
>   sip thrice seated on his haunches and with water to reach his heart,* 
>   wipe his lips three times  or, according to some, twice,  and touch
>   them with water once or, according to some, twice. With his right hand
>   he should sprinkle water on his left hand and on his feet and head,
>   and then touch the organs,* namely, the eyes, the nostrils, and the
>   ears, with water.  He should then wash his hands with water.  Even
>   though he is already pure, however, when he is preparing to take his
>   meal, he should sip water twice, wipe his lips twice, touch his lips
>   with water once, rub the inside of his lips, and then sip water
>
> **Apasthambha Dharma Sutras 1.16.1-10**

So, again there is no use of any mantras.

All other Smritis describe the process in more or less the same manner. Some however suggest sipping the water along with chanting portions of Gayatri mantra but then that is not a Vaishnava mantra.

Tantras and Puranas, however, prescribe mantras for achamana.

The Shakta (and Shaiva) Brahmins will do achamana using the mantras - **atma tattvaya swaha, vidya tattvaya swaha, shiva tattvaya swaha (sometimes a 4th sip with sarva tattvaya swaha)**. And, these are not Vaishnava mantras.

> Having thus made obeisance to the Devi, he should leave his house,
>   placing his left foot first, and then make water, discharge his
>   bowels, and cleanse his teeth (36). He then should go towards some
>   water, and make his ablutions in the manner prescribed (37). First of
>   all let him rinse his mouth, and then enter the water, and stand
>   therein up to his navel. He should then cleanse his body by a single
>   immersal only, and then, standing up and rubbing himself, rinse his
>   mouth, saying the Mantra the while (38). That best of worshippers, the
>   Kula-Sadhaka, should then sip a little water and say: Mantra
>   Atma-tattvaya Svaha
>
> After that he should again sip water twice, followed in each case by
>   the Mantras
>
> Vidya-tattvaya Svaha.
>
> Shiva-tattvaya Svaha, respectively. Lastly, he should rinse the upper
>   lip twice (39)
>
> **Mahanirvana Tantram, Chapter 5**

Similarly, the Vaishnava text Gautamiya Tantram prescibes the use of mantra "Keshavaya namah, narayanaya namaha .." etc. The Devi Bhagavatam prescribes the same mantras with Swaha replacing Namaha.

> Firstly make the ordinary Âchaman three times, and, while inhaling,
>   drink a little of the water of Âchaman, repeating “Om Kes’avâya Svâhâ,
>   Om Nârâyanâya Svâhâ, Om Mâdhavâya Svâhâ.” Then wash your two hands,
>   repeating “Om Gobindâya Namah, Om Visnave Namah.” Then by the root of
>   the thumb rub the lips repeating “Om Madhû sûdanâya Namah, Om
>   Trivikramâya Namah.” So rub the mouth, repeating “Om Vâmamâya Namah,
>   Om S’rîdharâya Namah.” Then sprinkle water on the left hand, saying
>   “Om Hrisîkes’âya Namah.” Sprinkle water on the legs, saying “Om
>   Padmanâbhâya Namah.”
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam 11.16**

The Kali (or Kalau) achamana consists of sipping using the root Krim and then doing anga-nyasa using various other mantras. Similarly, the Tara achamana is done with the mantra Hum. In the same way there is a separate Chinnamasta achamana.

So, Shukracharya or any other Brahmins have  plenty of options to choose from. Not all are required to perform the Vaishnava achaman.

Comment: You have very good knowledge about traditions. :-) @Rickross

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Thank you for the applause :) but the fact is that I  have very little knowledge.

Comment: That shows your modesty. @Rickross